# Which React Material-UI components add a spacing to my page (like a row class in Bootstrap)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created a project using React and [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) for React.

Coming from a Bootstrap background, I've noticed none of these components come with any margin around their components.

In Bootstrap I can add spacing like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

But I've got no idea what component to use to create such spacing.

I'm currently using custom classes to create some sort of spacing, but it doesn't feel correct.

**App.tsx:**

```
<Container maxWidth="lg" className="container-padding">
    ...
</Container>
```

**App.css:**

```
.container-padding {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

For example, add spacing between these elements with an existing component:

[image]

I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a grid layout component in `@material-ui` similar to Bootstrap grid. Both are based on a 12-column grid.

The below example demonstrates it,

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

return (
<Box m={4}>
 <Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <Paper>xs=6</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <Paper>xs=6</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    <Paper>xs=3</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    <Paper>xs=3</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    <Paper>xs=3</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    <Paper>xs=3</Paper>
  </Grid>
 </Grid>
</Box>
<Box mx={3}>
  Box 2 content
</Box>
<Box my={3}>
  Box 3 content
</Box>
);
```

So to summarize,

m - all sides margin

mx - Horizontal spacing

my - Vertical spacing

Comment: This would be perfect, but the spacing above my element doesn't work. See update for example

Comment: Use Box element with m/mx/my to achieve spacing. Updated the code, Please check

Answer (score 1):

I've used the "[Lobotomized Owl](https://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls/)" selector by Heydon Pickering: `* + *`.

I created a 'container' component `Vertical.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  vertical: {
    '& > *+*': {
      marginTop: '1.5rem',
    },
  },
}));

const Vertical = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Box className={classes.vertical}>{children}</Box>;
};

export default Vertical;
```

Then use it in any other components e.g. `Example.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Vertical from './Vertical';

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <Vertical>
      <Component/>
      <Component />
      <Another />
      <AnotherComponent />
    </Vertical>
  );
};

export default Example;
```